# Reference field in nested map in Firestore security rules

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I have this data structure:

[image]

and need a rule that only allows updates when the `city` attribute is not changed:

```
match /requests/{requestId} {
  allow update: if (request.resource.data.diff(resource.data).unchangedKeys().
     hasAll(["customerlocation.city"]))
```

That doesn't work, because the `diff` result only shows the `customerlocation` field, but not the `city` attribute.

Is it even possible to achieve what I want? I know there are limitations wrt what you can do with nested objects in security rules, but I have might just missed something.

Comment: You should be able to get the keys of the `customerLocation`, but I'm not sure I understand what your documents look like. Can you add a screenshot of a document to the question?

Answer (score 2):

I believe that the solution Aion proposed is the only one that will work if you don't want to change your data structure and have to do this inside of the Firestore rules.

I don't know what your overall data structure looks like, but you could move `customerLocation` out to its own collection. Then you would store a DocumentReference to `customerLocation` inside of the `request`.

You could also create a cloud function with `document('requests/{requestId}').onUpdate()` and check if the city changed. If it has, then change it back in there. This would require you to keep track of the fact that you changed back the property though. Otherwise, the function would keep triggering and flipping the values.

Answer (score 1):

Why dont you directly compare the field value ?

```
allow update: if request.resource.data.customerLocation.city
 != resource.data.customerLocation.city;
```

Comment: Because of maintainability. The original question is a simplification of a more complex rule that takes further attributes into account. Technically your suggestion should work, but it will be a nightmare to maintain it.

Answer (score 0):

I would simply recommend that you check to see if the City is still in it's default value, in this example I put that as "Default City" (that default would likely be nil)

```
match /requests/{requestID} {
  allow update: if request.resource.customerLocation.city == "Default City"
}
```

Since your entire Firestore database is not referenced it may look slightly different in your project, but I think logically this will work.

Comment: I don't think you can accomplish this without setting a default value. Couldn't you also add a flag to the document to see if a certain field has been edited, and if it has it becomes 'changed'? That would make it easier than setting a default in the city since the user would possibly see that.